# How can I set the title of a DOM button using javascript if I know the id of the button?

Tags: javascript

I have a button:

```
<button id="abc">abc</button>
```

How can I set the title property of this button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get a reference to the element:

```
var yourBtn = document.getElementById('abc');
```

Then, set its `title` property:

```
yourBtn.title = 'Something';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute`method

```
document.getElementById('abc').setAttribute("title", "Your title");
```